# Creating a Windows failover cluster using PowerShell reported an error

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell

I used the following PowerShell command to create a Windows failover cluster on Windows server 2016,

```
New-Cluster –Name MyCluster –Node 5011-a1ca9b8d.kc.com,8766-a1ca9b8d.kc.com –StaticAddress 10.177.12.14,10.111.36.100 -NoStorage
```

And then I get this error:
[image]

I found this in the event viewer:

```
New-Cluster System.AccessViolationException
应用程序: powershell.exe
Framework 版本: v4.0.30319
说明: 由于未经处理的异常，进程终止。
异常信息: System.AccessViolationException
   在 <Module>.CreateCluster(_CREATE_CLUSTER_CONFIG*, Int32 (Void*, _CLUSTER_SETUP_PHASE, _CLUSTER_SETUP_PHASE_TYPE, _CLUSTER_SETUP_PHASE_SEVERITY, UInt32, UInt16*, UInt32), Void*)
   在 MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Cluster.Create(System.String, System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1<MS.Internal.ServerClusters.IPAddressInfo>, MS.Internal.ServerClusters.ClusterActionCallback, MS.Internal.ServerClusters.AdminAccessPoint)
   在 MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Configuration.CreateClusterConfigurationNoCno.PerformCreateCluster(MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Configuration.ActionArgs, MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Configuration.ActionUpdateHelper)
   在 MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Configuration.CreateClusterConfigurationNoCno.PerformAction(MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Configuration.ActionArgs)
   在 MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Configuration.CreateClusterConfigurationNoCno.InternalPerformAction(MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Configuration.ActionArgs)
   在 MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Configuration.ConfigurationBase.PerformActionWrapper(MS.Internal.ServerClusters.BackgroundOperationStatus, BackgroundOperationArgs)
   在 MS.Internal.ServerClusters.BackgroundOperation`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].BackgroundOperationProc(System.Object)
   在 MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Background+<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<EnqueueWorker>b__0(System.Object)
   在 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   在 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   在 System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   在 System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()


错误应用程序名称: powershell.exe，版本: 10.0.14393.206，时间戳: 0x57daccf5
错误模块名称: CLUSAPI.dll，版本: 10.0.14393.2879，时间戳: 0x5c89ed25
异常代码: 0xc0000005
错误偏移量: 0x0000000000001e2b
错误进程 ID: 0xfe8
错误应用程序启动时间: 0x01d7424b59d92212
错误应用程序路径: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
错误模块路径: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CLUSAPI.dll
报告 ID: 3216f5c4-9690-4f79-8d40-65ee6ebcbf77
错误程序包全名:
错误程序包相对应用程序 ID:
```

I tried to install .NET Framework 4.7 and 4.8, but the above errors still exist.

But I use the WSFC manager to create can succeed. What should I do?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. I can't even see what this has to do with SQL Server either. Seems like a question for [sf].

Comment: Sorry Larnu, I created the Windows failover cluster for SQL Server Always On

Comment: Did you run [`Test-Cluster`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/test-cluster) validation tests beforehand?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning  Yes, I ran `Test-Cluster` before `New-Cluster` . The tests reported some warning level failures, which I don't think are fatal for cluster creation. Because I also see these warnings when I create with Cluster Manager, but the cluster can be created successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everybody, by adding a parameter [-AdministrativeAccessPoint Dns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/new-cluster?view=windowsserver2019-ps#parameters), I solved the problem.

```
New-Cluster –Name MyCluster –Node 8766-a1ca9b8d.kc.com –StaticAddress 10.111.36.100 -NoStorage -AdministrativeAccessPoint Dns
```

I created the Failover Cluster for SQLServer Always On, and I chose the domain free mode.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the System.AccessViolationException issue when creating a cluster and the issue turned out to be port 3268 was blocked to the domain controller.

Apparently Global Catalog is required.